# Combobox selected Item does not match with its selected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, combobox

I faced with that issue which appears with spaces after letters finished more than Combobox.SelectedItem's length. Why? How can I fix this issue?

Below is showing my issue as visual its a very short and small video.
[Here is a small video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUd0HePGA1g)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Main
WithEvents bsData As New BindingSource
Dim sConn As New SqlConnection
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PC-N39;Initial Catalog=Esi01;Persist    Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sas"
    sConn.Open()
    Try
        Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable("MyTable")
        myTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Group Code"))
        myTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Description"))
        myTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("NothingSerious"))
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * from tbUnit", sConn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default)
        Dim myRow As DataRow
        While dr.Read()
            myRow = myTable.NewRow
            myRow.Item(0) = dr(0)
            myRow.Item(1) = dr(1)
            myRow.Item(2) = dr(2)
            myTable.Rows.Add(myRow)
        End While
        dr.Close()
        Dim myData4 As DataTable = myTable
        ds = New DataSet()
        ds.Tables.Add(myData4)
        MultiColumnCombo1.DisplayMember = "Group Code"
        MultiColumnCombo1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
        MultiColumnCombo1.ColumnWidths = "50;150"
        MultiColumnCombo1.DataSource = myData4
        MultiColumnCombo1.Text = String.Empty
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    sConn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type is MultiColumnCombo1 ? I suppose it's a third party component.
As far as I can see in your video, it seems that it takes the biggest element in your data, take it's length and add spaces to other elements to make them the same size.

You probably won't be able to change the component's behavior, but you can apply the same logic to what you enter in your `TextBox` : adding spaces to make them match. Or if you simply need to make a condition that test if they are equal, you can do as follow :

`if(YourComboboxSelectedItem.Trim() == StringYourAreComparingItTo)`

See [String.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx), that will discard the extra whitespaces.

Comment: Yes Its a third party one. I know Trim function and I also used it in combobox.selecteditem.text after its selected while the control pass the selecteditem through combobox.text but it was nothing to do that.

Comment: Okay so I have some trouble to understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove the spaces in the 3rd party component ? If so, Why exactly ?

Comment: I've tried to pass selected item with trim function through combobox.text but there wasn't any change on combobox selected item I was still seeing white spaces. Actually That's my issue to solve,

Comment: Well, this will entirely depend on the 3rd party component. You should probably include it's name in your question. If it comes from a know control library (infragistics and such), you can even add the corresponding tag. You will get a better help this way.

Comment: Someone told me that that probably a lack of feature od Datatable which retrieve data from Sql table.

Comment: I don't remember such problem with Datatable.. Have you made some test to verify this ?

Comment: I don't know too, I couldn't find a suit time to time research about that but if I wouldn't find a resolution then I'll do my own solution while insert or update data into table.